# Is there a way to completely disable copy/paste functionality in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, copy-paste

I'm looking for a way to completely disable the copy/paste functionality in Visual Studio (2005 if it matters). The reason behind this request is that I want to prevent myself from doing too much copy/paste while coding.

Thanks to all for your answers!

Comment: Too much codinghorror blog :)

Comment: remove the ctrl key from your keyboard

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490884/why-is-copy-and-paste-of-code-dangerous

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

Download [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Save this as GoAwayN00b.ahk and double click it.

```
#ifWinActive, ahk_class wndclass_desked_gsk

^c::
^v:: MsgBox Go away n00b !
```

Additionally, you may want to provide visualisation for xtra stimulation. Save this picture and display it on hotkey press (left for exercise):

[alt text http://images.paraorkut.com/img/funnypics/images/g/go_away_noob-12269.jpg](http://images.paraorkut.com/img/funnypics/images/g/go_away_noob-12269.jpg)

BTW, copy/paste + [CLCL](http://www.nakka.com/soft/clcl/index_eng.html) = FTW. I don't use VS without it.

**EDIT**:
Alternativelly, you can Customize Keyboard (right click toolbar -> Customize->Keyboard) and delete Edit.Copy and Edit.Paste hotkies. 
However, above script works with any VS and on any computer while this solution needs to be setup individually.

Answer (score 16):

No.  Use self-discipline instead.

Comment: I hate this kind of answers but damn, this deserves an upvote :)

Comment: You might want to trap the alternate keyboard shortcuts as well:
`Cut: Shift+Del  
Copy: Ctrl+Ins  
Paste: Shift+Ins`

Comment: this is really not a useful answer! For example: I have somebody in my team who is ALWAYS copy&paste-ing stuff around the project. This leads to extremely bad and redundand code. If he would have to work without c&p for a couple of weeks, I am sure this would help a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The other day my daughter asked if I had a duller saw so she wouldn't cut herself as easily while pruning some bushes. Of course now it takes longer to prune the bushes...

Comment: Perhaps this should be refactored to a haiku.

Answer (score 4):

As asked: The other day my daughter asked if I had a duller saw so she wouldn't cut herself as easily while pruning some bushes. Of course now it takes longer to prune the bushes...  Refactored.

```
For dull saw she asked
No injury while pruning
Free time now all gone
```

Comment: I hope you didn't copy and paste that original text... just kidding!

Comment: With syntax-highlighting no less - I love it!

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed the [point of the article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001257.html) but in you really want to, [here are some resources](http://www.secretgeek.net/copy_paste_dont_do_it.asp) for battle copypasta.

Answer (score 3):

As Jeff lines out in his [current blog entry](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001257.html), copy&paste itself is not the problem, but how you use it. As copy&paste can also be used to speed up "typing"/editing, you shouldn't disable it.

Answer (score 3):

Prise your C button out of the keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, this also keeps you away from using this troublesome letter anywhere in your kode. Kode is so mukh more readable if you don't use this konfusing kharakter.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste is a valuable tool. You should be careful about what you copy and paste, but you don't need to disable it. Just watch what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to disable CTRL-drag as well!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find some sort of util that allows you to global remap key combinations. Then all you have to do is re-map the copy/paste combinations do to something else. Just an idea.

Although I think you are crazy for wanting to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write a small service program that will monitor clipboard changes and upon notification replace the clipboard text with "Content protection from lazy asses".

Comment: You should be able to find something on Google you can paste into a project

Comment: But the search and following paste operations will take place on your PC, right? Which is now protected by our little tool.